# SonarQube. Custom repository with custom rules. Included rules is presented as Rule Template

Tags: python, sonarqube, sonar-plugin

It was necessity to write my own repository with a bunch of specific python rules and I wouldn't like to use Xpath to include it in sonar context.

I've implemented my own module where I used almost the same implementation from sonar-python modules: Sensor, ProfileDefinition, RulesDefinition.

I've only changed implementation of CheckList and excluded from Sensor a highlighting and metrics.Basing on this parts I've created Plugin and added them in sonar context.

Everything work perfect, my custom rules raises issues but all these rules are flagged as `Rule Template` and I cannot create new QualityProfile   basing on it.

What do I omit?

Answer (score 3):

Currently SonarPython only support XPath rules and not custom java rules.

But, if you create your own sensor, when you declare your RulesDefinition, you should NOT call `setTemplate(true)`

```
NewRule rule = ...
....
rule.setTemplate(true);
```